# Trying to recall fantasy book about twin brother and sister assassins forced to share a body

Tags: story-identification

I read this book in the 90's.  As I recall it centered around brother-sister twin assassins; after the brother's body was taken over or killed, the sister scooped up the brother's essence and they "live" together in her mind as she searches for a way to get her brother's body back.

I thought it may have been a Mercedes Lackey title, as I remember the book's cover being in her style, but I can't seem to find it as one of her books.  The background world had some fantasy elements but I don't remember much.  I remember a passage in the book about the hero being frustrated that her broken wrist would never be as strong as an unbroken wrist.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Take a look at [this post](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) for some possible additions to your question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This sounds like  [Fifth Quarter](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/175312.Fifth_Quarter) by Tanya Huff.

It was published in 1995 and the blurb matches your description:

- brother and sister assassins
- brother body is stolen and his spirit is forced to share sister's body
- hunting for brother's body

It has been a long time since I read it, so I don't know if it has the bit regarding the broken wrist. The cover art is a similar style to Mercedes Lackey's works,  so that is another match.

This is the second book of the series but the first with these characters.

Comment: Bingo!  This is the one.  Hats off to your great memory and thank you!